# remove item from comparable array

Tags: java, arraylist, comparable

I'm very new to java and my first question is what is this Comparable thing? and in my sample code, why `Class Bag<T extends Comparable<T>>`?? What's the purpose?

My second question is how to remove an item from this Comparable array. I have wrote the removeMin method, I have found the item, I named the variable "min", how do I go on and remove this min item from the arrayList? Thanks a lot!

Here's some partial code:

```
public class Bag<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {
    private int MAX_ITEMS = 10; // initial array size
    private int size;
    private Comparable[] data;

    public Bag( ) {
        //data = (Comparable []) new Object[MAX_ITEMS];
        data = (T []) new Comparable[MAX_ITEMS];
        size = 0;
    }

      public Comparable removeMin(){
          Iterator<T> iterator=iterator();
          T min = iterator.next();
          while (iterator.hasNext())
          {  
             T next = iterator.next();
             if (min.compareTo(next) > 0) 
                min = next;
                ****************************************************
                How to remove this min item? 
                ****************************************************
                }
          return min;
          }
```

Comment: What does the `iterator()` method do? Does `data` have to be an array or can you use some other data structure?

Comment: Hi I used the iterator in the method to locate the minimum element and yes data have to be the array in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is this `Comparable` thing?

It is a generic interface that can be implemented by classes whose instances you need to be able to compare with each other.  `Comparable<T>` has a single method `int compareTo<other T>`.  The implementation of the method is supposed to compare `this` with the `other` instance

> In my sample code, why `class Bag<T extends Comparable<T>>`? What's the purpose?

This is saying that your `Bag` class is a generic class with a type parameter `T`.  The `T extends Comparable<T>` bits is saying that `T` must be some class that implements `Comparable<T>`.

---

> My second question is how to remove an item from this Comparable array.

That is for you to figure out, based on your knowledge of how arrays work.  The big constraint you have to deal with is that an array's size cannot be changed, so there is no magical operation that will simply remove something from the middle of the array.

There are two approaches:

- Create a new array containing just the elements that you don't want to be removed.  (Hint: copy them)
- Move the elements around in the existing array to "fill the hole" left when you conceptually remove an element.  (Hint: notice the `size` field.  What is it there for?)

Assuming that you wrote the `removeMin` method from scratch, I think you have gone down a blind alley with trying to use an iterator there<sup>1</sup>. Try coding it to operate directly on the `data` array.

The `removeMin` problem has two parts:

1. Find the index in `data` for the smallest element
2. Remove the element at that index

Hint: the first part *requires* that you look at *every* element ... and this has to be done *before* you do the removal.  This should be reflected in your code.

---

<sup>1 - If you were using an `ArrayList<T>` or similar, then using `data.iterator()` would be a reasonable choice.  The problem is that arrays don't directly support the `Iterable` API.</sup>

<sup>Now if you are required to make your `Bag` class implement `Iterable<T>`, then you *could* use the iteration mechanism you implemented for that purpose in your `removeMin` method.  But even there, the API is not ideal for the purpose.  You would still need to iterate the collection twice.  Once to find the smallest element, and a second time to remove it.  And removal via an iterator means that the iterator would need to implement the *optional* `Iterator.remove()` method .... which brings you back full circle.</sup>

Comment: "I think you have gone down a blind alley with trying to use an iterator there."  haha u got me

Answer (score 1):

> what is this Comparable thing

In simplest term it specifies how the items can be compared to each other . For example in your case your class `Bag` may contain any item so you used generic type `T` but you want your items to be comparable to each other too, so you used `T extends Comparable<T>`

The [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)  interface has a method `compareTo` which is used to compare the items. You can read more about it in JLS.

**Now you may be wondering why do I need to compare items?**
Imagine if you have no way to compare then how can you say `5` is a bigger number than `1` or why `A` comes before `B` in alphabets. They do so because we have some order for them and based on them we can compare then. Similarly you may like a items in your bag to be comparable.

> how to remove an item from this Comparable array

To iterate over the items you already seem to use an `iterator`

```
 Iterator<T> iterator=iterator();
 T min = iterator.next();
```

You can use same iterator to remove the item if it matches your condition. So your code should be `iterator.remove()`. But you should also ensure for null check and existence check at all relevant places

Comment: thank u! very good answer! just one more question please, where should I insert the code iterator.remove(), i tried it after the min=next, it indeed removed the min item, however, returned the next minimum item. How can I do it so that it removes and returns the same min item? thanks

Comment: After removing the item breakout and return `min` as the minimum item is still there.
`if (min.compareTo(next) > 0) 
                iterator.remove();
                 break;
   }
          return min;`

Comment: You need to ensure yourself that your condition and all are correct as I can but I wont help :) . This is a part of learning :)

Answer (score 1):

It is the [`java.lang.Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. `<T extends Comparable<T>>` is a generic type, at compile time Java will require that an instance provide an implementation of `int compareTo(T o)` which (from the Javadoc) returns *a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.* Also, you might back your `Bag` with a `Collection` (instead of an array), like

```
class Bag<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {
    private List<T> al = new ArrayList<>();

    public Bag() {
        super();
    }

    public T removeMin() {
        Iterator<T> iterator = iterator();
        T min = iterator.hasNext() ? iterator.next() : null;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            T next = iterator.next();
            if (min.compareTo(next) > 0) {
                min = next;
            }
        }
        if (min != null) {
            iterator = iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                T next = iterator.next();
                if (min.compareTo(next) == 0) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return al.iterator();
    }
}
```

Note that [`Iterator.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) says (in part) *the behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.*

Answer (score 1):

The comparable interface is implemented in order to define a comparison mechanism to your custom types.
array are usually size fixed so you cannot just remove an item without copying the remaining ones to a new array. I suggest to change your array to dynamic list:

```
public class Bag<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {
    private int size;
    private LinkedList<T> data;

    public Bag() {
        data = new LinkedList<T>();
        size = 0;
    }

    public Comparable removeMin() {
        Iterator<T> iterator = iterator();
        T min = iterator.next();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            T next = iterator.next();
            if (min.compareTo(next) > 0)
                min = next;
            data.remove(min);
        }
        return min;
    }

}
```